# How do you get the key for an Immutable object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I’m a bit new to Immutable.js and need to loop through a `Map()` which has nested objects. I essentially need to extract the key for the parent and then the values for the child of each object.

This is the structure I am working with. I want to get the keys (`a` and `b` in this case), and then output the child values.

```
  Map({
    a: {
      foo: 1,
      bar: 2
    },
    b: {
      foo: 3,
      bar: 4
    }
  });
```

I’ve tried something like this but can’t really get it working:

```
  const mappedObj = data.toArray().map((d) => (
    <div>
      <h1>{d.get('[key??]')}</h1> // <- this is obviously wrong, but can't figure out how to get the [key]
      <ul>
        {d.map((a) => (
          <li>
            <span>{a.get('foo')}</span>
            <span>{a.get('bar')}</span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  ));
```

Comment: Map has a built in `forEach` method you can use to iterate of the Map...

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
const map = new Map();

map.set('a', { foo: 1, bar: 2 });
map.set('b', { foo: 3, bar: 4 });

// Map { 'a' => { foo: 1, bar: 2 }, 'b' => { foo: 3, bar: 4 } } 


map.forEach((key, value) => console.log(value)) // a, b
```

Comment: This answer definitely got me where I needed to get. Cheers!